# How to write a full path in a batch file having a folder name with space?

Tags: batch-file

I am writing following command in batch file

```
REGSVR32 E:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\xyz.dll
```

After running this command I am getting following error

```
LodLibrary(e:\Documents) failed specified module could not be found.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Put double quotes around the path that has spaces like this:

`REGSVR32 "E:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\xyz.dll"`

Answer (score 1):

CD E:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data

E:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data>**REGSVR32 xyz.dll**

Answer (score 0):

```
start "" AcroRd32.exe /A "page=207" "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\abc xyz def\abc def xyz 2015.pdf"
```

You may try this, I did it finally, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I made a **

> automatic-network-drive connector

** using a batch file.

Suddenly there was a networkdrive called "Data for Analysation", and yeah with the double quotes it works proper!

looks a little bit different but works:

```
net use y: "\\share.blabla.com\Folder\Subfolder\Data for Analysation" /USER:domain\username PW /PERSISTENT:YES
```

Thx for the Hint :)