# Sqlcmd: Error: Syntax error at line 17 near command ':r ' in file

Tags: sqlcmd

I need to execute multiple sql files using a batch file. So, I created a file **CREATE_DB.sql** with following code:

```
/* SCRIPT: CREATE_DB.sql */
/* BUILD A DATABASE */

-- This is the main caller for each script
SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

PRINT 'CREATING DATABASE'
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE NAME = 'MSSQLTIPS')
DROP DATABASE MSSQLTIPS
GO
CREATE DATABASE MSSQLTIPS
GO

:On Error exit

:r  C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\BATCheck\CREATE_TABLES.sql
:r  C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\BATCheck\TABLE_INSERTS.sql
:r  C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\BATCheck\CREATE_INDEXES.sql
:r  C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\BATCheck\CREATE_PROCEDURES.sql

PRINT 'DATABASE CREATE IS COMPLETE'
GO
```

Then, I create a batch file **create_db.bat** with following code:

```
    SQLCMD -E -dmaster -i"C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\BATCheck\create_db.sql"
PAUSE
```

But, on double-clicking the batch file it shows the following error:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Syntax error at line 17 near command ':r         ' in file 'C:\Users\XYZ\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\BATCheck\create_db.sql'.
```

This, I think, is due to the Spaces in the file paths, but how to get rid of this error?

Comment: Try the following link if it helps

[Link 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347501/how-write-full-path-in-batch-file-having-folder-name-with-space)

Comment: According to [this forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/5a28022d-3000-4dfd-85de-22f64e817149/sqlcmd-r-and-spaces?forum=sqltools) putting double quotes around the file `:r "C:\myfile.sql"` should fix this. Note also that the filepath is relative to the sqlcmd startup directory, so just `:r CREATE_TABLES.sql`may also work

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used double quotes earlier and the bat file ran but the tables, procedures etc. were not created in the databse. So, I wrote the lines "USE MSSQLTIPS "  and "GO"  before the line ":On Error exit" and it worked.