# Sqlcmd: Error: near command 'Ë'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm importing a 7GB `.sql` file and I got this error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Syntax error at line 7863597 near command 'Ë' in file 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\project\MS_SQL_Dump\MS_SQL_Dump.sql'.

I'm currently trying running the import command again but with double quotes around the path/filename. I don't know if that will work though, it was suggested on a comment on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29182452/sqlcmd-error-syntax-error-at-line-17-near-command-r-in-file).

Any idea what the issue is and how to resolve it?

Comment: Please provide statement at line 7863597

Comment: I've tried opening it with EmEditor but the file is too big.

Comment: Do you have a full backup (`*.bak`)?

Comment: all I've got is a `.sql` file

Answer (score 6):

It could be because you have a $ in your query. Try adding -x to the end of your sqlcmd statement, ie:

```
sqlcmd -i c:\import.sql -x
```

Worked for me...hope it helps someone!

source: https://ts.apexsql.com/the-sqlcmd-error-syntax-error-at-line-xyz-near-command-x-in-file-file_name-sql-error-is-encountered-when-running-sql-script-via-sqlcmd-utility/

Comment: Been stuck on this for a few hours now. This worked a treat, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> all I've got is a .sql file

In this case try to load this script view [dbForge for SQL Server](https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/studio/):

[image]

and provide error message...

Comment: I did try this and after a while the program didn't respond, I left it for a while and it appeared to be responding but it didn't go any further than 28% of the file.  I left it overnight too.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this before and this error is due to quotation marks.
Please on the quoted_identifier setting which is defaulted to OFF.

Please take a look on sqlcmd options here : [sqlcmd utility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

> When SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is ON, identifiers can be delimited by double quotation marks, and literals must be delimited by single quotation marks. When SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER is OFF, identifiers cannot be quoted and must follow all Transact-SQL rules for identifiers. For more information, see Database Identifiers.

To set this to on just add sqlcmd option "-I" (take note of the case )

Like this :

```
sqlcmd -I
```

---

Comment: Unfortunately I got the same error when adding that switch in:  `sqlcmd -I -d dbname -U dbuser -S server -i "C:\inetpub\w
wwroot\project\MS_SQL_Dump\MS_SQL_Dump.sql"`

Comment: Try to add '-x' maybe there is a dollar symbol in your script
sqlcmd -s Server_name -d Database_name -E -i c:\Temp\Recovery_script.sql -x

Comment: That seemed to help, getting another error now `Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Server WIN-EG69IP4LH04, Line 59
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string '
<div class="WordSection1">
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri, 'sans-seri
f';color:#1F497D;">Thanks .</span></p><p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size:11pt;font-family:Calibri, 'sans-seri
f';color:#1F497D;"></span></p><p>Â </p>
<div>
`