# closing a program with a space in the name

Tags: batch-file

So I know this is pretty basic stuff but I'm trying to make a batch file that will open some programs and then close then all when I'm done. The problem is that one of the programs has a space in the title of it and I would rather not rename it.

Example:

```
@echo off
start /IM Example Program.exe
pause
taskkill /F /IM Example Program.exe
end
```

I know that I could simply change the name of the program to `Example_Program`, but I would rather not. Is there anyway to do this?

As an edit I have tried:

```
@echo off
start /IM "Example Program.exe"
pause
taskkill /F /IM "Example Program.exe"
end
```

When I put parenthesis around the file name, it opens a command prompt as if I'd right clicked on it and clicked open command prompt here or something like that.

Comment: Doesn't it work as is? with the space? if not, `%20` represents a space.

Comment: Did you try surrounding the name with quotes?

Comment: [Dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347501/how-write-full-path-in-batch-file-having-folder-name-with-space); just add quotes.

Comment: What is `end`? This is an unknown command which is the reason why I left it out in my answer. And why not using `start "Any Title" /wait ...` and halt batch execution until started application terminated itself?

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
start "" /IM "Example Program.exe"
pause
taskkill /F /IM "Example Program.exe"
end
```

??

Comment: that doesnt work i've tried and every time instead of opening the program it opens a command prompt at that location rather than the program itself

Comment: Start assumed that the first set of quotes it finds is the window's title. You need another set before the /IM.

Answer (score 0):

Use following batch code:

```
@echo off
start "Any title" /IM "Example Program.exe"
pause
%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /F /IM "Example Program.exe"
```

Command **start** interprets first string in double quotes as optional title. Therefore it is necessary to explicitly define a title for the command window which can be also an empty title, i.e. just `""`.