# Double quotes is not working for calling a folder with spaces from Command Prompt

Tags: batch-file, testng

I am trying to create a bat file to run testng from command prompt. Problem is that my path contains many folders with spaces in its name. I followed the step mentioned in [How to write a full path in a batch file having a folder name with space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347501/how-to-write-a-full-path-in-a-batch-file-having-a-folder-name-with-space) and added double quotes for the folder with space in its name but the issue is that the application is also considering the folder name with quotes and hence unable to find the given folder.

Here is my command.

```
set ProjectPath="C:\Test\ABC Online"    
echo %ProjectPath%
set classpath=%ProjectPath%\bin;%ProjectPath%\Framework Jar Files\*
echo %classpath%
java org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%\testng.xml
```

but everytime getting an error "Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG". In the above code when I echo Projectpath, I am getting something like this.

```
 "C:\Test\ABC Online" (Double quotes)
```

If I change the folder name to ABC_Online and run the same command without double quotes, it work pretty fine.

Am I missing something. Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `set` command line, the quotation marks are part of the value, and there are trailing spaces at your command line:

`set ProjectPath="C:\Test\ABC Online"`<kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd><kbd>SPACE</kbd>

So the command line `java org.testng.TestNG "%ProjectPath%\testng.xml"` expands to this:

```
java org.testng.TestNG "C:\Test\ABC Online"    \testng.xml
```

---

Use the following syntax so the spaces and the quotation marks do not become part of the variable value:

```
set "ProjectPath=C:\Test\ABC Online"
```

When using the value later, put quotes like  this:

```
java org.testng.TestNG "%ProjectPath%\testng.xml"
```

Comment: Thank you. I must have by mistake entered some space while posting the question here but space was not issue but your other solution worked for me.

I tried this code earlier
    set "ProjectPath=C:\Test\ABC Online"

but didn't called testng like you mentioned above.

Thanks again. I have accepted your answer. Cheers :)

Comment: The spaces cause `\testng.cml` to be treated as a separate argument for `java`, so the problem was a combination of the spaces and quotation mark placement...