# program is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: batch-file

Right so i'm just trying to get a batch file working and I keep getting this as my starting line for my admin is.

```
CMD C:\Windows\System32>
```

All I want to do is run this command

```
C:/Program Files/AMD/RyzenMaster/HPET.bat.
```

and I cant get it to work. it just keeps coming up with

> program is not recognised as an internal or external command.

I really don't know what to do please can somebody help.

Comment: Are you sure that `C:/Program Files/AMD/RyzenMaster/HPET.bat`  exists? Try to open `C:/Program Files/AMD/RyzenMaster` in the windows explorer and try to find `HPET.bat`

Comment: just checking but i have to get it enabled to allow me to use an application that then allows me to control cpu speeds and ram speed without going into the bios

Comment: What is the exact command line you use? You do know that if a file path have a space it  must be inside quotes ("")?

Comment: just check it doesnt come up for some reason

Comment: i didn't know that it has to be in quotes

Comment: the exact line was Program Files/AMD/RyzenMaster/HPET.bat.

Comment: CMD handles space as parameter separator. You are trying to run a program called `C:/Program` with `Files/AMD/RyzenMaster/HPET.bat` as an argument. `C:/Program` does not exists so you have an error

Comment: so would i need to put it like this?                                                         "Program Files"/AMD/RyzenMaster/HPET.bat

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use spaces in CMD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376113/how-to-use-spaces-in-cmd)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write a full path in a batch file having a folder name with space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347501/how-to-write-a-full-path-in-a-batch-file-having-a-folder-name-with-space)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMD handles spaces as a parameter separator. So  your command is trying to run a program called `C:/Program` with `Files/AMD/RyzenMaster/HPET.bat` as an argument. `C:/Program` does not exists so you have an error. To fix it, use 
`"C:/Program Files/AMD/RyzenMaster/HPET.bat"` instead (notice the quotes " ).

Comment: i think i now got it enabled now. i need to restart my pc but if this works you are amazing back in a min

Comment: It worked, Thank you so much, you are a god send. i'm defiantly going to have a look into learning more command and things like that. but once again thank you so much